# Некорректно работает sort() в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

```
sortNums(prop) {
        this.database.sort(function (a, b) { 
            var response = 0;
            if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
                console.log(a[prop] + '>' + b[prop])
                response = 1
            }
            if (a[prop] < b[prop]) { 
                console.log(a[prop] + '<' + b[prop])
                response = -1
            }
            if (a[prop] = b[prop]) {
                console.log(a[prop] + '=' + b[prop])
                response = 0
            }
            return response
        })
    }
```

Значение b[prop] возвращается одно и то же весь цикл сортировки.
И почему-то даже меняет значения одинаковых свойств в массиве объектов на это же.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в `if (a[prop] = b[prop])`, для сравнения надо использовать двойное `==`.

```js
const arr = [{'a': 5}, {'a': 6}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 2}]
const prop = 'a'

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var response = 0;
  if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
    console.log(a[prop] + '>' + b[prop])
    response = 1
  }
  if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
    console.log(a[prop] + '<' + b[prop])
    response = -1
  }
  if (a[prop] == b[prop]) {
    console.log(a[prop] + '=' + b[prop])
    response = 0
  }
  return response
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Я контекста Вашего проекта не знаю, но что-то мне подсказывает, что Вам подойдет простое:

```
sortNums(prop) {
    this.database.sort((a, b) => a[prop] - b[prop])
}
```